# How to add a certain amount of 0's to begining of a cell?

Tags: excel

I need a cell to be 10 characters long, and to fill in 0's at the begining of a number to make it 10 characters.

Example: Cell A1 is 1990, I need it to be 0000001990. 
Cell B2 is 82. I need it to be 0000000082.

The cell can be any range of numberrs.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/88870/adding-a-zero-before-values-in-an-excel-spreadsheet-column/1052430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the TEXT function, as in:

=Text(A1,"0000000000")

Comment: Yes! Thanks Vic, exactly what I needed. Cheers :)